# Why is IRequiresHttpRequest lazily loaded?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to set up a set of rules that execute under one of 3 conditions:

```
HttpRequest.HttpMethod = "Put"
HttpRequest.HttpMethod = "Post"
HttpRequest == null
```

This last one will occur in the case where I'm trying to validate a POCO from a windows client. (see my other question here [re-using ServiceStack validation in Winforms offline client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318735/re-using-servicestack-validation-in-winforms-offline-client)).

I was hoping to create a an if() statement around my RuleFor()s in my validator, but HttpRequest is always null at this point (the documentation warns that it is lazily-loaded and available only in the validation delegates).

The only other solution I've come up with is adding a .When() to every one of my rules that makes this check, but these seems like way too much repetitive code.

Is there a common code point where I can check the HttpRequest object to determine if it's null, or the verb is put/post?

Comment: Does something like 'RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () => ...' help here? More info here -> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#fluentvalidation-for-request-dtos

Comment: The rulesets work for limiting the service, but when I group rules into a ruleset in this way, they are no longer fired from outside the service (in my case from the offline client).